# Best practices in resolving code conflicts between teams

Tags: testing, integration-testing, branching-and-merging

I am looking for solutions to the scenarios below that can arise when merging code:

- There is a basic conflict within the code, Team A and Team B both update the same file, and it then reports as a conflict.
- There is a functionality conflict where Team A develops selected functionality that causes conflicts with functionality of Team B
- There is a performance issue, Team A develops a change which works fine, but changes by Team B cause a performance hit within Team A's functionality.

On the final release side of things, who is responsible for the final delivery of the integrated package from both parties?

During the release both parties will be under pressure to make their deliveries. Should code conflicts occur, what is the process to get them resolved? If Team A checks in first, and Team B then identifies some code conflicts, based on the standard approach below they would resolve the conflict. Who is then responsible for the change, as both parties will have tested their code within a system test environment and verified the changes? However, the integrated test of both changes will not happen until SIT (System Integrated Testing). Thus, if Team B has changed the code to resolve conflicts within Team A's change this then invalidates any testing that has happened and they may not be across the requirements to fully testing the requirements correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The current best practice is to have an automated test suite which thoroughly tests all functionality of the entire application. (Deferring testing to an integration testing phase that happens after development is definitely not a best practice.)

- When any developer updates the code, it is that developer's responsibility to update the tests (in the same commit) to test her changes and to ensure that all tests pass. That includes performance tests.
- After any update, it is the current best practice for all developers working with the code to pull the update into their workspaces as soon as possible. Each developer is responsible for resolving any source code conflicts between their changes and the newest version of the code in the repository and ensuring that all tests pass. Usually different developers work on different parts of the code and there will not be conflicts. If there are non-trivial conflicts, it probably means that two developers should have been working together. They should resolve to do better next time.

Regarding delivery, the current best practice is for the master branch to be deliverable at any time. If all the tests pass, we know the software is ready to deliver. So there is nothing to be done on the development side to deliver the software. If the software is to be delivered to a customer, the best person to decide is the product owner or product manager, who will base their decision on business requirements. In fact, the best practice in environments where it is possible (such as web applications) is to automatically deliver each revision of the software for which all the tests pass.